# How can I provide a reference to a struct that is a sibling?

Tags: rust

I have a structure with some shared immutable data, and another
structure that makes use of that data. I'd like to bundle these into
one structure because they make logical sense together. However, I
don't understand how I can provide a reference to the object itself
during construction:

```
struct A {
    v: i32,
}
struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a A,
    b: i32,
}

struct C<'a> {
    a: A,
    b: B<'a>,
}

fn main() {
    C {
        a: A { v: 13 },
        b: B { a: &??, b: 17 },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Chris' answer, there are two issues to solve:

1. have a syntax that unambiguously allows referring to a sibling
2. make it so that borrowing rules can still be verified

It is relatively easy to cover (1), a simple `&self.a` could be used for example, anchoring `self` in the most outer type possible; however it seems that covering (2) would be much more difficult: nothing in the structure itself points to this relationship, and therefore it is not evident that `self.a` is borrowed.

Without `self.a` being marked as borrowed, you run into plenty of unsafe behaviors, such as possible destructive behaviors, which Rust is designed to stay clear of.

Answer (score 3):

This simply cannot be represented in safe Rust code.

In cases like this, you may need to resort to dynamic borrowing with things like [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).

Comment: I've used RefCell, but could you add a small example of how I would use it in this case? Would I need to rewrite `B` to take advantage of this? If so, what if `B` were provided by an external source?