# How to get the equivalent of C++ initializer lists

Tags: rust

I have two simple structures like that:

```
struct Foo {
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo;
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    pub fn new(foo: &'a mut Foo) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar {
            foo: foo,
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the structure `Bar` needs a reference to a `Foo` to work on. This is how I use it:

```
let mut foo = Foo::new();
let mut bar = Bar::new(&mut foo);
```

Now I want to create a "glue" structure to handle the creation of all these `Foo`s and `Bar`s. So I just want the structure `Container` to have 1 `Foo`, 1 `Bar`.

I tried doing something like:

```
impl Container {
    pub fn new() -> Container {
        Container {
          foo: Foo::new(),
          bar: Bar::new(&mut foo),
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesnt work, I cannot reference the field `foo` from the `bar` initializer.
I basically want to mimic the following C++ code:

```
Container::Container() :
    foo(),
    bar(&foo)
{}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Of course using any kind of dynamic allocation/reference counting would be highly overkill here.

**--- EDIT ---**

To be clear, I want to create the Rust code equivalent to this C++ snippet:

```
struct Foo {
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo& f) : foo(f) {}
    Foo& foo;
};

Foo f;
Bar b(f);

struct Container {
    Container() : f(), b(f) {}
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
};
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Here is what I ended up doing, using `Rc<>`.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo {
  pub bar: Rc<Bar>,
}

impl Foo {
  pub fn new(bar: Rc<Bar>) -> Foo {
    Foo {
      bar: bar,
    }
  }
}

struct Bar {
  a: u8,
}

impl Bar {
  pub fn new() -> Bar {
    Bar {
      a: 42,
    }
  }
}

struct Container {
  pub bar: Rc<Bar>,
  pub foo: Foo,
}

impl Container {
  pub fn new() -> Container {
    let bar = Rc::new(Bar::new());
    Container {
      bar: bar.clone(),
      foo: Foo::new(bar.clone()),
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  // Just checking that we get the same bar for both
  // inside Container and inside Foo
  let c = Container::new();
  println!("{:p}", &*c.bar);
  println!("{:p}", &*c.foo.bar);

  // So from what I understand, here bar is on the stack
  // then byte-copied to the heap where that Rc<> will point?
  let bar = Bar::new();
  println!("{:p}", &bar);
  let foo = Foo::new(Rc::new(bar));
  println!("{:p}", &*foo.bar);

  // Sad story is that using this Rc<> I now use the "cuteness"
  // and safety that I had with reference borrowing:
  // struct Foo<'a> {
  //   bar: &'a mut Bar,
  // }
  // impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  //   pub fn new(bar: &'a Bar) -> Foo<'a> {
  //     Foo { bar: bar }
  //   }
  // }
  // let bar = Bar::new();
  // let foo = Foo::new(&bar);
}
```

But this is not really satisfying, I feel like I used a machine gun to kill a rabbit. Any insight greatly appreciated :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I provide a reference to a struct that is a sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349778/how-can-i-provide-a-reference-to-a-struct-that-is-a-sibling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simplified view of memory. I'm making up sizes and offsets to illustrate the problem, they bear no resemblance to reality.

We start by stack-allocating a brand-new `Container` with your desired structure at address 80.

```
80 Container
..   foo: Foo (size 8)
88   bar: Bar
       foo: &Foo (size 8, value 80)
```

Now we pass the structure by value into a method, or return it from where we created it, like a constructor would. Moving by value involves a bit-for-bit copy, so let's move it to address 40:

```
40 Container
..   foo: Foo (size 8)
48   bar: Bar
       foo: &Foo (size 8, value 80)
```

Uh oh! The inner `foo` now points to a piece of memory that *isn't part of our struct anymore*! That's the type of unsafe code that Rust tries to prevent.

Conceptually, there are some ways to prevent this. Rust could track that a pointer is really just some offset into itself and then rewrite the value every time the item is moved. I don't know, but that seems expensive. It might also need some special syntax to denote it.

A solution I would like to see would involve indirection and the heap. If we heap-allocated the top-level `foo` *and if Rust tracked stack and heap lifetimes separately*, then we could have something like:

```
== stack
80 Container
..   foo: Box<Foo> (size 8, value 10)
88   bar: Bar
       foo: &Foo (size 8, value 10)

== heap
10 Foo (size 8)
```

Moving the structure would change the addresses, but the value would be safe-and-sound because `Foo` is off in the heap and not moving around.

I don't know that there are any plans to support this kind of solution, but I don't think there's been much clamor for it, either. Maybe it's not even technically feasible!

Comment: I get your point here, but I don't understand how this is related to the problem. Doesn't that just imply that `Container` is not implicitely byte-copyable, and thus should implement the `Copy` trait to handle this case? (and initialize the reference to point to the newly created other field)

Comment: [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) doesn't have any methods to implement, none of the marker traits do. `Copy` also specifically says: "Types that can be copied by simply copying bits".

Comment: My bad, I misread the meaning of the `Copy` trait. I think your explanation is starting to find its way through my brain... thanks a lot.

Comment: @AurélienVallée: it is less a matter of copy and more a matter of *move*. For simplicity reasons, all structures in Rust are byte-movable; this has huge advantages in terms of designing containers for example because 1/ it guarantees the operation is No Throw and 2/ it is easy to bulk-move (memcpy). To regain that, C++ containers have to have multiple execution paths depending on whether the move/copy is `noexcept` and whether a type is trivially movable/copyable; the alternatives are eliminated at compile-time thanks to monomorphisation, but that's a lot more complex.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to express this concept in safe code in Rust.

Comment: There has to be a "rusty" way to handle this case? Maybe I could use `Option<Foo>`, and check in each function that there is something inside?

Comment: I may misunderstand, but I think this *must* be unsafe because rust "moves" always involve memcpy's. So, if you have a function `fn takeContainer(c: Container) {...}`, the address of `c` in the body of this function is allowed be different than the address of `c` in the caller. This means that the address of `c.f` and `c.b` will also change. So the contents of `c.b` have to change when the value is moved. But that won't happen with a `memcpy`, so the reference would point to the wrong address.