# Fighting with / not understanding Rust borrow checker

Tags: rust

I started writing Rust code a few days ago, and just now had my first encounter with the borrow checker.

```
#[derive(Clone, Eq, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vm<'a> {
    instructions: Rc<InstructionSequence>,
    pc: usize,
    stack: Vec<Value<'a>>,
    frames: Vec<Frame<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Vm<'a> {
    pub fn run(&'a mut self) {
        loop {
            let instruction = self.instructions.get(self.pc).unwrap();

            match instruction {
                &Instruction::Push(ref value) => {
                    let top_activation = &mut self.frames.last_mut().unwrap().activation;
                    self.stack.push(Vm::literal_to_value(value, top_activation))
                },

                _ => ()
            };
        };
    }
}
```

[full code here](https://github.com/exceptional-lang/exceptional-rs/blob/4a124c50c9b1f78ef713e6e14077939031f9771d/src/vm.rs#L153-L159)

Rust gives me the following errors:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.frames` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/vm.rs:157:47
    |
157 |                     let top_activation = &mut self.frames.last_mut().unwrap().activation;
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                                               |
    |                                               second mutable borrow occurs here
    |                                               first mutable borrow occurs here
...
181 |     }
    |     - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.frames` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/vm.rs:157:47
    |
157 |                     let top_activation = &mut self.frames.last_mut().unwrap().activation;
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                                               |
    |                                               second mutable borrow occurs here
    |                                               first mutable borrow occurs here
...
181 |     }
    |     - first borrow ends here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I don't understand why it's getting borrowed twice. What's going on?

Comment: We need a [MCVE], because I cannot reproduce your issue without `InstructionSequence`, `Value` and `Frame` and the definition of `literal_to_value`... try to isolate your issue on the Rust Playground and edit your question with a link there. Apart from that, in general you SHOULD NOT have the same lifetime on the `struct` *and* on `&self`. It's a very bad idea, and only occurs when the `struct` tries to store references to its own members... [and that's not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349778/how-can-i-provide-a-reference-to-a-struct-that-is-a-sibling).

Comment: An `&mut` borrow conflicting with itself is often because the reference is kept alive until the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you push on the stack keeps a mutable borrow on `self.frames` active. On the second loop iteration, that borrow is still active, so you can't take a second borrow on `self.frames`.

`Vm::literal_to_value` doesn't need a mutable reference to the activation object, so you can change your code to take an immutable reference instead:

```
match instruction {
    &Instruction::Push(ref value) => {
        let top_activation = &self.frames.last().unwrap().activation;
        self.stack.push(Vm::literal_to_value(value, top_activation))
    },
    _ => ()
};
```

That makes `run` compile, but then your tests fail to compile. That's because with this signature:

```
pub fn run(&'a mut self)
```

you're linking the lifetime of `self` with the lifetime parameter on `Vm`. Essentially, the type of `self` here is `&'a mut Vm<'a>`; the fact that `'a` occurs twice here, combined with the fact that it's a mutable borrow (rather than an immutable borrow) tells Rust that the `Vm` *maintains a mutable borrow on itself within one of its fields*. Therefore, the `Vm` object will "lock" itself once you call `run`. That means that after calling `run`, you can't do anything else on the `Vm`! The bottom line is that [you can't have a field in a struct that is a reference to a value that is owned by the same struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/234590).

Comment: This is a good explanation of what's going on, thanks! It also made me realize that my program doesn't allow static lifetimes like I was trying to do. Activation needs to be mutable, so I used an `Rc<RefCell>`